# Cascade comboboxes with ReactiveCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactive-property

I'm trying to setup linked comboboxes with ReactiveProperty and ReactiveCollection.
I have ItemViewModel like this:

```
public class ItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ItemViewModel (string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Range = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public List<int> Range { get; }
}
```

And parent view model:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    this.Collection = new ReactiveCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        this.Collection.Add(new ItemViewModel (i.ToString()));
    }

    this.SecondCollection = this.ObserveProperty(x => x.SelectedItem).Select(x => x.Value.Range).ToReadOnlyReactiveCollection();
}

public ReactiveCollection<TestViewModel> Collection { get; }

public ReadOnlyReactiveCollection<int> SecondCollection { get; }

public ReactiveProperty<TestViewModel> SelectedItem { get; } = new ReactiveProperty<TestViewModel>(mode: ReactivePropertyMode.None);
```

I have collection of ItemViewModel (Collection property), when SelectedItem change to item from Collection property, i need to fill SecondCollection from Range collection of SelectedItem

How can i make it?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to explain your question further.

Comment: I have collection of ItemViewModel (Collection property), when SelectedItem change to item from Collection property, i need to fill SecondCollection from Range collection of SelectedItem.